# How does row ptr for the Compressed Row Storage method work?

Tags: sparse-matrix

I am trying to understand how does the row ptr for compressed row storage method work? I am reading this article: http://netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node91.html#SECTION00931100000000000000

The val and col_ind are kind of straight forward but I am confused about how the row ptr array are generated? 
For example, how did you get the second 3 and third 6? 
According to the article, row_ptr[n+1] should equal to nnz +1. 
However, the definition given in the above article does not make sense to me. NNZ is the number of non zeros in the original matrix which should be a constant. If so, we would end up with the same val for all elements inside the row ptr array.
Can someone please help me understand this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally understand how it works. 3 refers to the fact that the first row has only only two non zeros element. 6 refers to the fact that the second row has 3. Hope that helps someone. So the nnz here is a variable rather than a constant